# File download links in a textbox in ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I have a list of PDF files retrieved from an Azure storage location.
Currently, in my Web App, I filter and gather all of the PDF file names that the user may want and display them in a `<asp:TextBox>` by assigning a string (e.g. "PDF1.pdf\r\nPDF2.pdf\r\nPDF3.pdf") to the Text property of the TextBox. So they appear like this:

```
PDF1.pdf
PDF2.pdf
PDF3.pdf
```

I know the location of the files - e.g. "https://mypdfs.blob.core.windows.net/pdf-repository/" - so can prepend that info to each file for the link (but still would like to only show the filename itself to the user).

I would like the users to be able to click on any of the PDF filenames and have the file download and appear in their local PDF reader.  However, I'm not seeing how to do this in a TextBox.

Can this be done within a TextBox?  If not, what are the normal methods of doing something like this?

Comment: You can't do this with a `asp:text box`. Normally you'd have a `asp:repeater` with links to the file or service to download the file.

Comment: try to implement <ul><li></li></ul>

Comment: So, a `asp:repeater` is the only way to do this?  Given my string of PDF filenames, what would be the best way to implement the repeater?

Comment: You can use Editor for Displaying HTML as text, and using Stringbuilder create HTML Format string with all PDFs and Assign it to Textbox who has Editor/CKEDITOR with Textmode=Multiline.